# Limit Point of the Following Set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A:=\{d^{-1}+kd:0<d<1,k=0,1,2,\dots,\}$. Does the set $A$ have any real limit points?

The motivation for my question is that I would like to find a closed set of 0 Hausdorff dimension that contains an arithmetic progression of EVERY gap $0<d<1$.

Comment: Why? It seems to me that the set is very dense as $d$ goes to 0.

Comment: If you consider $k=0$, this set contains the set $\{ d^{-1}: 0<d<1\} = (1, \infty)$. Hence $A= (1, \infty)$, which is an open set, and all of its points are limit points.

Comment: Anyway, let $X$ be any set containing arithmetic progressions of every gap. Since gaps are uncountable, $X$ must be uncountable. However, uncountable sets have at least one limit point.